# Create a log file from a copy batch file

Tags: batch-file, logging, copy, output

I have a COPY batch file that copies a file to multiple computers (about 300, which is being read from a separate text file), and I would like to see the results of the file copy.  If I can see both the successful and failed file copies, that would be great.  But it'll be fine if it's only possible to see the failed copies.

Here's the code that I have now, which is working great.  The files are being copied to the test computers I have setup.  Thank you all in advance for taking the time to help me out with this.

```
for /f "Tokens=*" %%a in (c:\computers.txt) do (set MyVar=%%a& call :next)

pause
goto EOF

:next
echo %MyVar%

if exist "\\%MyVar%\C$\Users\Public\Desktop" (
    Copy "C:\document search.website" "\\%MyVar%\c$\Users\Public\Desktop\" /Y 
    Copy "C:\document search.website" "\\%MyVar%\C$\Users\Public\Favorites\" /Y
) else ( copy "C:\document search.website" "\\%MyVar%\c$\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\Document Search.url" /y
     copy "C:\document search.website" "\\%MyVar%\C$\Documents and Settings\All Users\Favorites\Document Search.url" /y 
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add the script below at the beginning of your script

```
call :Logit>>C:\logfiles_location\file_transfer.log 2>&1
:Logit

echo Start time is: %date% %TIME%
```

Comment: This is somewhat of the result log I wanted.  I am able to see which computer failed the copy or which one succeeded.  This may be tough, and may be asking too much, but is there a way to have it strip down to show which computer failed the copy, and to exclude all that have succeeded?

Comment: I noticed that I had to press Enter on the keyboard to initiate the command after running the batch.

Comment: I think I needed to press Enter at a point where the batch is in PAUSE.

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything. i Use a similar script and there is no need to press Enter when the job completes.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I was looking at the log file, and it was waiting for me to press the Enter key due to the pause command.  I removed PAUSE and now it's working like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect the output of the `copy` command to a file. However, the `copy` command will only print the result of the copy, without the file name included (e.g. `1 file(s) copied.`). So, you should add an extra log line to your log with the action you are doing.

```
REM Flush the previous log file
echo. > someLogFile.log

for /f "Tokens=*" %%a in (c:\computers.txt) do (set MyVar=%%a& call :next)

pause
goto EOF

:next
echo %MyVar%

if exist "\\%MyVar%\C$\Users\Public\Desktop" (
    echo Copying to %MyVar% desktop... > someLogFile.log
    Copy "C:\document search.website" "\\%MyVar%\c$\Users\Public\Desktop\" /Y >> someLogFile.log

    echo Copying to %MyVar% favorites... > someLogFile.log
    Copy "C:\document search.website" "\\%MyVar%\C$\Users\Public\Favorites\" /Y >> someLogFile.log
) else ( 
    echo Copying to %MyVar% desktop... > someLogFile.log
    copy "C:\document search.website" "\\%MyVar%\c$\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\Document Search.url" /y >> someLogFile.log

    echo Copying to %MyVar% favorites... > someLogFile.log
    copy "C:\document search.website" "\\%MyVar%\C$\Documents and Settings\All Users\Favorites\Document Search.url" /y >> someLogFile.log
)
```

Comment: may be it will be easier if you turn on the `echo` ?

Comment: When I tried using this, the log file showed up empty.  I tried to modify it a little bit, but nothing seemed to work.  demo.b's answer worked to get the results that I needed. It provided a full log of what the command went through.

Comment: @Mike, I modified it a bit, namely I changed the `>` redirection to a `>>` redirection, to append the text to the log file rather than overwriting it every time.

Comment: @Laf, this is only recording the last line of the code.  I used demo.b's code, and it's working really well.  I do appreciate all the assistance, it's not going by unnoticed!